# When I install odoo V9 it say me, "Could not execute command 'lessc'"?

Tags: odoo-9

When I try to install odoo_v9 it successfully install, and create demo database it also created, but after install demo database it give me error like "Could not execute command 'lessc'"....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs almost everytime with a fresh installation of Odoo.
(Especially with Ubuntu 12.04)

> 1. First run these three commands in your terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
```

> 2. Then you install nodejs:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

> 3. You can then check version of nodejs using:

```
node -v
```

> 4. It should be at least greater than > **0.10**

```
npm -v
```

Should return a version at least > **1.4**

> 5. Then finally execute the following command, whick will update npm to a newer version as well as install the less plugin:

```
sudo npm install -g npm
sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css
```

Comment: Im on a mac, ive installed and updated them.  node 7.2.0 and npm 3.10.9.  I still get could not execute command lessc.  Im on a mac with python 2.7.12.  Please help!